# JSON-like syntax type to React Component Properties Parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to figure out how to convert the following React function into a React component class:

```
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/styles.css';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp;
```

Since I am working with strict TypeScript compiler settings, when I write:

```
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  override render() ...
}
```

...I must supply the template (generic parameter?) arguments to the component like:

```
class MyApp extends React.Component<MyPropertyType, MyStateType>
```

But I do not know how to convert this syntax `{ Component, pageProps }: AppProps` to the React component parameter type.

I have never seen this syntax, which I think is saying a JSON object with fields of `Component` and `pageProps` and the object is type `AppProps`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this syntax [...] is saying [an] object with fields of `Component` and `pageProps` and the object is type `AppProps`?

You guessed absolutely right! This is [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) (here of a function parameter).

Therefore in your case, `AppProps` is the type for your class-based component as well:

```
class MyAppClass extends React.Component<AppProps> {
  override render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props
    return <Component {...pageProps} />
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wChTgA7GJKTdJOAQTDAAUcwBnOAb1LhwAwrkiUk1AFyJiMAHQjwEcdQAqATzBIANALhgUAcyQcI3abwC+pa5gCulDMGVwAsupZgAFL2GjlEjDa+kYmnDyW0p6m3ACUfHpEMHZQlHAAPIpigXxyeQbGMVyWcAD0AHw25GgANihcPO6eQnUNcEgAHjSUACY8yOjyWQHU6dHh5QmCEAButFDAPYxEvbRe8fyCgmjKXPC+wypBIYXhcCUAvHAwABbAXHJg4XqCSSlpmf5HufmhRSUVPTWaxAA)